# what is the advantages of using a waterfall model to solving a project on an aeroplane

Tags: waterfall

Based on the software development life cycle use the waterfall model to resolve the following project.an aeroplane has to be designed to every little detail upfronts.this is possible mostly because we have been building airplanes for a lot longer than we ve been building software.furthermore,because any two airpalnes share perhaps 80% of the DNA and any 2 software applications share perhaps 20% of their DNA

Based on the above information,explain the process invoved from interception of d project to its final stage to design and maintain the airplane project.state d advantages and disadvantages of suing this model to solve this project.

So der is no answer to dis questions ryt?

Comment: Aside from the fact that this is part of a misguided homework assignment, what's your actual question?

Comment: What I'm curious about is: was the bad English copied from the assignment verbatim, or added in an attempt to fool a Google search for the assignment?

Comment: I am not sure about the rules but surely its not OK to ask homework/assignment questions here, especially when one cannot even be bothered to paraphrase it.

Comment: @Muhammad AFAIR, it's fine to do so... as long as the question and answers are broadly applicable/useful to many people, not just those who need it for an assignment. Of course, that won't stop the teachers from punishing for it...

Answer (score 2):

The waterfall model as a sequence of activities to be completed in order is not applicable to building and aeroplane.  Certainly not one of any size.  However, it does layout major activities and the order in which they are started.

Any major airplane design goes through a lot of design, build (usually a model), test iterations before the real building begins.  Even when they get to full scale, there will be extensive testing of the first models, possibly leading to redesign.

Early documents on the Waterfall model, such as one by [Dr Winston W Royce,](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc838p/Process/waterfall.pdf) included feedback loops to earlier processes.  I expect project managers stripped the feedback loops so that they could indicate completed steps earlier.  Also the skills sets for the various steps can be significantly different.  There is likely pressure to release the resources required for a step once the initial work is done.

Comment: I appreciate that you answer the question that a future reader may have and end up here rather than answer the assignment for the OP. Good answer.